# Looping n data in excel and saving it as nested loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, list, nested-loops

I am relatively new in programming so any help is very much appreciated. My project requires me to read an excel file. I did this using openpyxl. A sample excel file is shown below:

```
          Number      Hours       Days        R1      R2
   1       1           3           5          2       1
   2       2           4           2          1       3
   3       3           2           3          2       0
   4       4           3           2          1       5
   5       5           6           7          7       2
```

Header names appear in the 1st row. The thing is R1 and R2 changes depending on the excel file being read. It can just be R1 or can be R1, R2, R3, R4, etc. The code I currently have is as follows but this only gives me R1.

```
    R = []
    u_need = []
    for x in range(min_column, max_column-2):
      for row in range(2, max_row+1):
        for col in range(min_column+3, max_column+1):
          if (sheet.cell(row,col).value is not None):
            u_need.append(sheet.cell(row,col).value);
            break;
      print('U{} = '.format(x), u_need)
      R.append(u_need)
      break;

    print(R)
```

What I am trying to do is to store in R=[u_need] with length depending on the one being read in excel.

As an example of the solution I am looking for the given sample above:

```
       R = [U_need1, U_need2]
       U_need1 = [2, 1, 2, 1, 7]
       U_need2 = [1, 3, 0, 5, 2]
```

Comment: if you want the values R1 and R2 it would be simple and easy if you use pandas

Comment: I will read through it. I just wanted to ask why my loop is not 'looping'? The above code only gives me R = [[U_need1]] instead of R =[[U_need1], [U_need2]]. Note that U_need are integer lists.